# How to trigger pipeline for multiple project from single repo

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a gitlab repo which has two folders(**folder-a and folder-b**) in it, I want them to get triggered based on the commit on their folder. Currently I have a single gitlab.yml file which has below configuration. It triggers folder-a but not folder-b.

```
folder-a:
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: folder-a/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes: [folder-a/*]
folder-b:
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: folder-b/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes: [folder-b/*]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had the issue with folder-b .gitlab-ci yml file. this works fine, now able to trigger folder based on commits to the branches

Comment: What issue did you have in your `folderb/.gitlab-ci.yml`?